# SharePoint Framework Extensions not working on my tenant

Tags: office-365, spfx, sharepoint-framework, spfx-extensions

I want to try the `SharePoint Framework Extension` samples but had no luck for hours.

Even the `Allow Debug Script` - popup doesn't show up.

Is it possible to use those samples in an O365 SharePoint environment (Developer Site Collection) or do I need Office Developer Preview environment?

Comment: what is the query string URL you are building, make sure to use the proper Extension ID in URL and your `gulp` is running.

Comment: Yep. I did everything step by step from the tutorials. The "Hello World" example and the "Conditional Formatting" example

Comment: Recently the SPFx Extensions are updated RC. Follow the URL in below Answer by Gautam to identify if something is broken in your code. ALso try to check browser console for error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SPFx extensions are not yet ready for production use.

But with the recent update to RC, you can play with them in the Developer tenants or First release tenants.

If you have developer tenant, it should work there.

Reference - [Changes in SPFx extensions between Preview and RC](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/extensions/changes-between-dev-preview-and-rc)

Answer (score 0):

The hint with the "First Release"-Tenant solved my issue. I had to change the "Release preferences" in the Admnin center. The path is:

> Admin center -> Setting -> Organization profile -> Release preferences

You can choose "Standard release", "First release for everyone" or "First release for selected users"

[Official Microsoft description to configure First release](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-the-Standard-or-First-Release-options-in-Office-365-3B3ADFA4-1777-4FF0-B606-FB8732101F47)